# Is there an advantage to using 2d kernels in CUDA beyond convenience?

Tags: c++, cuda, dimensions

I'm wondering if there is any inherent advantage to having a kernel be > 1d besides the convenience of abstraction. I figure that if the dimension of the kernel is relevant, the answer might have to do with the layout of the gpu. I would generally prefer to stick to 1d and flatten higher dimensional data. Is there anything wrong with this approach on a technical level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even worse that what Jerome said... combining 2D/3D locations is *not* so cheap. Just think about it:

```
flattened_block_id = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.z * gridDim.y * gridDim.z;
flattened_thread_id = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.z * blockDim.y * blockDim.z; 
block_volume = blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z;
global_flattened_id = flattened_thread_id + block_volume * flattened_block_id;
```

And this is all when ignoring the dimension bounds. Which you can't do, generally. So, you need some sign extends, and half the multiplications and additions become 64-bit. That's a lot of operations! And just think about those cases where you have a condition such as:

```
if (is_nice(global_flattened_id)) { return; }
```

with that in place, you just made sure you have to pay for all those operations even when your thread isn't going to do anything.

Having said that... when I was writing kernels which work on 1D data, I also had the notion that these extra dimensions are just silly. Then I started actually having 3D (or 5D) data and they got useful very quickly :-)

Finally, remember: CUDA is a biproduct of [3D graphics shader evolution](https://download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/2004/Perfect_Kitchen_Art/English_Evolution_of_GPUs.pdf). It needed 3D representations before it needed you or me as users...

Comment: Thank you for your informative response. Follow up question: can the size of the dimensions be arbitrary, or should I be paying special attention to the actual layout of the gpu (i.e. initializing the kernel to the dimensions of my problem, or conforming my problem to the optimal dimensions of the kernel)? I understand this is something of a broad question. Do you know of any resources (videos especially) which could help to clarify the relationship between gpu architecture and kernel dimension? Thanks again

Comment: @classic_sasquatch_behavior: The sizes have different limits by dimension. x is the "large" dimension, y and z are "small"; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications).

Comment: While lines like `blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.z * gridDim.y * gridDim.z` looks terrible visually, they are not so computationally intensive because the GPU can typically use *FMA-based instructions* like `MAD` to compute it very quickly. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oTcq3PTv5) is an example. Note the number of move is surprisingly high in both implementations. The first implementation just use few additional relatively-cheap instructions. Besides this, I agree for the bounds and the rest ;).

Comment: @JérômeRichard:  Your example is for the 32-bit case only. For 64 bits, it looks like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/a4GM6af4W). The `mov`'s are for getting special register values (which is in itself not as cheap as you would expect).

Comment: Even for huge arrays, I expect the `flattened_block_id` not to overflow in 32-bits because each block should at least have 32-threads (for sake of performance). If there is an overflow, it would mean the array is bigger than 64 GiB which is too big to fit in the GPU memory (and using unified memory would be far more expensive). Only the `global_flattened_id` need to be in 64-bits (like in the other kernel). For the `mov`'s, do you know if the low-level assembly get them from a special purpose register, an in-RAM (cached) variable or from any other data source? IDK if they could be evicted too.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Not all kernels are `vectorAdd()`.

Answer (score 4):

The two are likely not equivalent in term of performance: Flattening 2D/3D locations is cheap, but computing 2D or 3D block locations from a 1D flattened locations is expensive as this should require a slow modulus/division (blocks are not always power of nor known at compile time). Not to mention that using 2D grids for 2D computations make the code a bit more readable (the intent is more clear). This is especially true for 3D kernels. Moreover, [dimensions are bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications). This may be a limitation if you want to perform computations on 2D arrays bigger than 2 GB.